# Failed to add a service reference to WCF service

Tags: wcf

When attempting to add a service reference to a WCF service to my .NET project I am getting an error:

> Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible. Make sure your service is running and exposing metadata.

After doing some research I decided to add a metadate exchange endpoint to my service:

```
<endpoint 
  address="mex" 
  binding="mexHttpsBinding" 
  contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
```

Now, after adding the enedpoint I am getting a different type of error:

> Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https].

What am I doing wrong here?

If I open service in the browser, it works just fine:

> https://alias.domain.com/ProjectName/MyService.svc?wsdl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

The issue was that some XSD references in WSDL, schemaLocation in particular. For some reason schemaLocation used machine name instead of the domain name. After I fixed that I was able to add a reference to the service

Answer (score 1):

`mexHttpBinding` is only for `http://` but as your service is exposed over `https://` you need to change it to `mexHttpsBinding`.

See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395212(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Actually then I got an error `Security settings for this service require 'Anonymous' Authentication but it is not enabled for the IIS application that hosts this service` And I cannot enable anonymous authentication on the server because it is disabled as needed for other applications that already reside on the server

Comment: @ElenaDBA Anonymous Authentication is configured on a per-directory (and per-Application) basis in your web.config's system.webServer element - so you can override it - unless your server was specifically configured to deny overrides.